# Unable to login to AppStore on Mac Mini

Tags: apple-id, mac-appstore

When I login to AppStore on Mac Mini, I get the message to review account followed by an error message

[image]
[image]

When I see the details in https://appleid.apple.com/account/manage, I get the below message.
[image]

Need help in fixing it and login to AppStore.

Comment: Did you speak to Apple yet? https://support.apple.com/contact